# Cordova release apk using gulp

Tags: cordova, gulp, ionic4

I am trying to use [gulp.js](https://gulpjs.com/docs/en/getting-started/quick-start) to build a release APK for my app. I am using this piece code to do so as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/cross-platform/tools-for-cordova/build-deploy/using-gulp-build-tasks?view=toolsforcordova-2015).

```
var gulp = require("gulp"),
    cordova = require("cordova-lib").cordova;

gulp.task("default", function (callback) {
    cordova.build({
        "platforms": ["android"],
        "options": {
            argv: ["--release","--gradleArg=--no-daemon"]
        }
    }, callback);
});
```

However, when I run this using `gulp default` it builds debug APK. The log that I am getting running the command is a follow:

```
[01:02:38] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/treat/apps/gulpfile.js
[01:02:38] Starting 'default'...
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting)
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/Code/Library/Android/sdk (DEPRECATED)

> Configure project :app
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)
registerResGeneratingTask is deprecated, use registerGeneratedResFolders(FileCollection)

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugRFile UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:prepareLintJar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithPrepareIntermediateJarsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:writeDebugApplicationId UP-TO-DATE

> Task :app:processDebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /Users/Code/Projects/treat/apps/platforms/android/app/google-services.json

> Task :app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:packageDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:validateSigningDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:signingConfigWriterDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformClassesWithDexBuilderForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:compileDebugNdk NO-SOURCE
> Task :CordovaLib:mergeDebugJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :CordovaLib:transformNativeLibsWithIntermediateJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:transformNativeLibsWithStripDebugSymbolForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:packageDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:assembleDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:cdvBuildDebug UP-TO-DATE

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 28s
46 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 45 up-to-date
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to build Ionic 4 apps then you should use the Ionic CLI, for example:

```
ionic cordova build android --prod --release
```

From docs:

- https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/cordova-build

Comment: I know you can do it using ionic cli, I have been doing exactly that until now.  Now instead I want to do it using gulp. Any pointers on how to do it using gulp will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, you get all sorts of people on here, sometimes it helps to point out the obvious :) I dont have any gulp tips.